# JSON parsing using .NET deserialize() with nested "list"

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing, serialization

EDIT: Simplified the classes

```
{
  "name": "Final Five",
  "bio": null,
  "noPlayers": "0",
  "roster": {
    "players0": {
      "playerId": "3516",
      "name": "Gate",
      "role": "Mid Lane",
      "isStarter": 1
    },
    "players1": {
      "playerId": "3826",
      "name": "Veritas",
      "role": "AD Carry",
      "isStarter": 1
    },
    "players2": {
      "playerId": "4054",
      "name": "Novel",
      "role": "Support",
      "isStarter": 1
    },
    "players3": {
      "playerId": "4142",
      "name": "Wizardry",
      "role": "Top Lane",
      "isStarter": 0
    },
    "players4": {
      "playerId": "4555",
      "name": "Metroid",
      "role": "Jungler",
      "isStarter": 0
    },
    "players5": {
      "playerId": "4554",
      "name": "Chau",
      "role": "Jungler",
      "isStarter": 0
    },
    "players6": {
      "playerId": "3847",
      "name": "Biofrost",
      "role": "Support",
      "isStarter": 0
    }
  },
  "logoUrl": "http://riot-web-cdn.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/lolesports/s3fs-public/final-five-logo.png",
  "profileUrl": "http://na.lolesports.com/node/3498",
  "teamPhotoUrl": "http://na.lolesports.com/",
  "acronym": "F5"
}
```

I have this json being received on my end. The problem I'm having is trying to parse the players as a list instead of individual elements since the number of players may vary. I've tried using arrays and lists. These are the classes I have set up

```
public class Player
    {
        public string playerId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
        public int isStarter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Roster
    {
        public Player players0 { get; set; }
        public Player players1 { get; set; }
        public Player players2 { get; set; }
        public Player players3 { get; set; }
        public Player players4 { get; set; }
        public Player players5 { get; set; }
        public Player players6 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object bio { get; set; }
        public string noPlayers { get; set; }
        public Roster roster { get; set; }
        public string logoUrl { get; set; }
        public string profileUrl { get; set; }
        public string teamPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string acronym { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my deserialization:

```
 Team team = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Team>(responseText);
```

Comment: Please show the deserialization code you've been trying out.

Comment: why can't you try something like this for example 
`List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(jsonString);` do simple google search as well too

Comment: @MethodMan: Clearly its not that simple

Comment: Is using another library like JSON.NET an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to deserialize into a dynamic object and convert from that to your strongly-typed object. Like so:

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(responseText);
```

The resulting `dict` object is a dictionary, with each property represented as a name-value pair in the dictionary. Nested objects, such as `roster` and its contained `playersX` objects are themselves represented as dictionaries.

So, for example, you would get to the `name` property of the `player1` object like so:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Veritas", dict["roster"]["players1"]["name"]);
```

If it helps at all, you could just make the `roster` property `dynamic`, like so:

```
public class Team
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object bio { get; set; }
    public string noPlayers { get; set; }
    public dynamic roster { get; set; }
    public string logoUrl { get; set; }
    public string profileUrl { get; set; }
    public string teamPhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public string acronym { get; set; }
}
```

Then only that property will be deserialized as a dictionary of dictionaries.